# How to get set of colours in an processed image using python PIL

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have an image and when I process it, I can´t get the colors.
Here is my code:

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open  ('imag.jpg')
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(im,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
from collections import defaultdict
by_color = defaultdict(int)
for pixel in thresh1.getdata():
    by_color[pixel] += 1
print (by_color)
```

If I run just the original image (`im`), works well. But when I run processed image (`thresh1`), the following error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

       File "file.py", line 62, in <module>
            ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(im,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
        TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'src'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this function:

```
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(im,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

to work you should read image using [cv2.imread](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#read-an-image) (returns `numpy.array`) rather than [PIL.Image.open](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open) (returns `Image` object).

Comment: I understood, so I need convert my image. 
`thresh1 = Image.fromarray(thresh1)`. Thank you.